# moveToNext() is false

Tags: java, android, cursor-position

```
//row --> 2
int row = mCursor.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
 if (mCursor.moveToPosition(i)){
  int val = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UTILI_COLLOC_ID_UTILI))
 }
}
```

**I don't understand because I have 2 rows in my query. But when I want to read the seconde row with "mCursor.moveToPosition(i)", so it's false...Why ?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just safely use

```
while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
// code
}
```

instead of for looping

Comment: Hmm ok, you made sure that mCursor.getCount() is really > 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 Rows : 0th & 1st . I think here your problem is because you are moving to next record in a loop & cursor already moved to last record. so it return you FALSE.

Solution: put **mCursor.moveToPosition(1);** out side of for loop.